# Android desktop log viewer

Tags: android, logging, log-viewer

My Android application may save logcat logs to a file. This log file is then sent to developers for analysis.

Is there a nice ***desktop*** android log viewer application, which would visualize these logs?

I wasn't able to find a ready to use tool in Android SDK. Maybe I missed something there?

Comment: Personally, I read logs with less and it's search feature, or occasionally emacs, but that's probably a less polished solution than desired

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Desktop tool for reading android logcat log file, the same as DDMS.**
[image]
***The purpose of this tool is to allow developers to quickly locate, analyze, problem-solving, rather 
than struggling in the log file.***

Feature:
http://code.google.com/p/androidlogcatviewer/wiki/KeyFeature

Download:
http://code.google.com/p/androidlogcatviewer/downloads/list

Discuss-group:
http://groups.google.com/group/androidlogcatviewer

Comment: I can't get this tool to read my logs I created with adb (neither "adb logcat -v long > somefile.log" nor "adb logcat > somefile.log"). When I choose a log file, nothing happens. How do you create the logs?

Comment: Got it, has to be "adb logcat -v time"

Comment: Didn't get it to run on OS X (Maverick) or Windows 8.1. Nice pic though. :/

Comment: In the discussion board, there are instructions on how to make this run on 64-bit Windows. Didn't start doing that, but just so you realize a) it needs to be done b) it's possible.

Comment: Even though it's java, it unfortunately won't run on my linux (Kubuntu 14.04, 32 Bit). It terminates with an exeption when trying to start.

Comment: Can somebody tell me where is the location of logcat file in my device?

Comment: How can I use this in windows? I can't find the link in the group section.

Answer (score 14):

I've tried [logview-0.19](https://bitbucket.org/mlopatkin/android-log-viewer/overview) - works fine for my 13Mb logs.

Make sure to mark ./logview and ./lib/logview.jar as executable when running in Linux.

Comment: Seems to do the job. I'm surprised by how few tools exist for this job. I feel an itch... :)

Comment: Another offline tool

Comment: This is my favourite ♥

Comment: @HenriquedeSousa what do you mean by "offline"? It is possible to capture live logs from the connected device with logview, you just need to set up adb location if the latter isn't on the PATH.

Answer (score 5):

I found [Online LogCat Beautifier](http://forgottenprojects.com/tools/android/logcat/) to which can colourize given LogCat for easy reading. Really nice tool and it uses JavaScript, which means nothing is stored anywhere!

[image: LogCat Beautifier in action]

### Update:

The link is no longer accessible, and luckily enough for us, Android Studio now supports pasting the LogCat into its "LogCat" tab (previously "Monitor"). Upon pasting, you'd have the options to search/click like a normal LogCat's log.

Comment: This is a tool to analyze _offline_ logcat records.

Comment: You should also check out Android Studio's "Analyze stacktrace" by going to **Analyze > Analyze stacktrace**. See this G+ post https://plus.google.com/+IanLake/posts/jk4x5RoyXJm

Comment: @HenriquedeSousa in case last comment didn't generate a notification.

Answer (score 5):

[Splinter Log](https://splinter-log.com) works on MacOS and can do a few things better than DDMS, like grouping tags, resolving pids to package name, etc. https://splinter-log.com

[image]

Comment: Looks promising, but Mac-only =(

Comment: ...and again, offline tool

Comment: How to use this for seeing log information of connected device ??

Comment: This answer is not clear on how to actually use the software to solve the problem presented in this question...

Answer (score 3):

I use *coloredlogcat* for viewing logcat logs on the console. You should be able to do the same.

```
cat logfile | coloredlogcat.py
```

It should work out of the box. If it doesn't, I'm sure only minor modifications are needed.
Have a look at this link [coloredlogcat](http://jsharkey.org/blog/2009/04/22/modifying-the-android-logcat-stream-for-full-color-debugging/) for details.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Android Debug Monitor or [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html) without Eclipse.

Comment: Just an update.. DDMS is now deprecated. Instead we should use: `sdk_path/tools/monitor`. On OSX, `ddms`can't save some custom filters I created, whereas `monitor` can.

Comment: Yes, that is _Android Debug Monitor_, but there wasn't any online details about it when I wrote my answer, and it is very similar to DDMS.

Comment: Nothing happened running `sdk_path/tools/monitor` on windows.

Answer (score 1):

I've tweaked log4j Chainsaw V2 and the (VFS)LogFilePatternReceiver to allow Chainsaw to read events from Android log files generated via logcat -v time

Download the latest developer snapshot of Chainsaw (Mac DMG and tarball available): http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy

Save this XML off as a file (after tweaking the fileURL):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="true">
<plugin class="org.apache.log4j.chainsaw.vfs.VFSLogFilePatternReceiver" name="android-log">
    <param name="appendNonMatches" value="true"/>
    <param name="autoReconnect" value="true"/>
    <param name="fileURL" value="file:/path/to/android/log"/>
    <param name="name" value="android-log"/>
    <param name="logFormat" value="TIMESTAMP LEVEL/LOGGER(PROP(PID)):MESSAGE"/> 
    <param name="customLevelDefinitions" value="V=TRACE,D=DEBUG,I=INFO,W=WARN,E=ERROR,F=FATAL,S=OFF"/>
    <param name="promptForUserInfo" value="false"/>
    <param name="tailing" value="true"/>
    <param name="timestampFormat" value="yyyyMMdd HH:mm:ss.SSS"/>
    <param name="waitMillis" value="2000"/>
</plugin>
</log4j:configuration>
```

And then after starting Chainsaw, select the 'Use a Chainsaw config file' option from the 'File, load Chainsaw configuration' menu, browse to this XML file, select 'always start Chainsaw with this configuration' and press OK.

Comment: This works well on os x, solving my problem that the Eclipse logcat view often stops working. Exactly what I was looking for! I see the latest stable build is dated after your post so I'm wondering if it's now good to use rather than the snapshot you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

I like [LogExpert](http://logexpert.codeplex.com/). It has great filtering options and it is pretty fast. So I have created a custom columnizer that parses LogCat logs. It has some improvements to be able to parse my custom logs with method and line. You can download it [here](https://github.com/Bhiefer/LogCatColumnizer).

Comment: Looks again like Windows only :-(

Comment: The link is broken. This link should be working: https://github.com/zarunbal/LogExpert

Answer (score 1):

Personally I like [TailExpert](http://tailexpert.neware.nl) which I use together with logcatUDP to capture logs from multiple android targets, logcatUDP sends the log over the network to tailexpert where I capture it and view the side by side. But you can also read the logs from file if you like, it's a tail program so it will add logmessages to the view when they arrive. You can filter messages on keywords and use colors to identify certain logmessages. The other thing I like is that in tailexpert you can create columnizers on the fly and easily hide one or more columns or change the column order. The program is packed with features and I recently just started to discover the use of notifications to place bookmarks on the fly and halt the log when a certain logmessages passes by, which makes navigation so much quicker. Just check it out, you can download it [here](http://tailexpert.neware.nl/index.php/Try_TailExpert).

Answer (score -1):

I went with http://mlogcat.tistory.com/ now, since [Logcat Offline Viewer](http://groups.google.com/group/androidlogcatviewer) quit its job probably due to JAVA update.