# Filter text like Android Studio/Eclipse logcat

Tags: android, text, logcat, android-logcat

When I'm working with a QA and I receive a text of logcat from them and it's very hard to read.
So I need a way to filter the text and highlight like in Android Studio/Eclipse. Does anyone know such a tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find what you want here : [Android desktop log viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325073/android-desktop-log-viewer)

**otherwise :**

You can give a try to Notepad++ (for windows) :

http://notepad-plus-plus.org/fr/

Then go to

```
Find > Mark then select what you want to highlight.
```

[image]

I haven't try the last build of Android Studio, but it may integrate `Scratch File` feature (from IntelliJ 14).

```
 Tool > new Scracth File > select plain text for example
```

than paste your logs and use `find` (Ctrl+F). Intellij/Android Studio keep highlighter your pattern.

[image]